Deciphering drywall labels for forensics
Is there any information I can obtain from the prints on this drywall, especially a date?

It reads 0118230162. I think it must be from the early 80ies (1981 or 1982) so "82" would match but nothing else would match a date.
I have another piece of the same wall that looks like this:

It reads 01/23/02 452 06:10 GAR.... I would read this as a piece of drywall from January 2002. But I mentioned above, this part of the house was likely built in 1981/1982, along with other parts of the drywall.
Hence, I suspect that this section of the drywall was actually replaced in 2002.
Does 01/23/02 correspond to manufacturing date January 23, 2002? And can the first drywall be matched with an (approximate) date?

I've been doing home building and repairs for almost 60 years...and never had this question come up.  So out of curiosity, why do you need to know?  I'm sure somewhere there is someone that worked in the manufacturing of drywall  that can answer, but I still must ask ...why?

@RMDman  Think OP just wants to know if the drywall was replaced, and if someone could tell by the different dates/numbers.

@crip659,  ok...but still why?   I guess I am of the old school, "If it don't matter, you don't need to know".

@RMDman  Sometimes it does matter if you want to find if the drywall is one of the bad ones.  Search for drywall recall does bring up quite a few hits(was quite surprised myself, drywall is drywall).

@crip659, understood, however if the drywall is one of the "bad ones" it would be evident by the rusted screws or nails or any metal anywhere near it. I would trust that visual info more than anything that comes out of the country known for "bad" drywall.  It would also be easy for the OP to say "I'm trying to determine if I have any Ch*****e drywall.

@RMDman it matters. First, for my curiosity because I’d love to learn about the history of my house. Second, I’m going through homeowners nightmare: Leaky window and had to replace my entire exterior wall incl framing. Now I saw this piece of drywall under the window. My suspicion is previous owners knew about the issue but just patched small part of the drywall.

@divB...and all that info will get you nowhere with the previous owner. If you do find the date of manufacture, it does not prove the PO installed with any nefarious intentions.

@RMDman Did I say my intention was a lawsuit? I just want to know the history of the house. If it was indeed replaced in 2001 it was one ownership period before. I am not exactly sure about 1981 section either so the code on the drywall would help with that too.

@divB, so bottom line is you are just curious and the information is just to satisfy your curiosity. So just say so.  I admitted I was just curious as to why you needed this info, since I suspected it was useless.

the first one does not look like a time stamp.   what's "62" supposed to mean?
